# Qt for Android - undefined reference to compress and uncompress

Tags: qt, android-ndk

In my Android native project, I need to use some core Qt functionality. Following the instructions at http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt5ForAndroidBuilding, I managed to build Qt for Android. I can see that all the generated archive files are stored in qtbase/lib directory.

I am linking my C++ code with libQt5Core.a, libQt5Bootstrap.a, and libqtpcre.a. Almost all of my Qt references are resolved exception two non-qt references - `compress()` and `uncompress()`. I have searched for these  symbols in `qtbase/lib/*.a` files but haven't found any definition.

So where are these two functions defined? Are they in one of the standard NDK libraries or do I need to build something separately?

It seems `qbytearray.cpp` is using these two functions. It seems these functions are defined if QT_NO_COMPRESS is not defined. Looks like I could get away with the unresolved errors if I could somehow define QT_NO_COMPRESS. How do I define this? Do I pass it to configure script?

```
$ ./configure -DQT_NO_COMPRESS ...
```

Hoping I could simply find references to the missing functions. Otherwise, please advice on how to achieve the second option. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out zlib is already part of Android NDK. All that was needed was -lz flag:

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -lz
```